# Expand div on first click and fade out div on second click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make a div expand to full screen on first click, and fadeout on second click with jQuery, I've written both the expand effect and the fadeout effect, but when I click the div, two effects happen at the same time. How could I trigger different events on different clicks? (only two clicks are needed)

Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.p1').click(function(e) {
    $('.title').toggleClass('fullscreen');
});

$(".p1").click(function(e) {
    $(".title, .p1").fadeOut(1000);

});
```

Here is my html:

```
 <div class="container">

    <div class="blur title">

    </div>
    <p class=p1>IN </br> PRAISE </br> OF SHADOWS</p>

</div>
```

The above question has been solved, but my project actually have more than one div :

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="blur title"></div>
    <p class="p1">IN </br> PRAISE </br> OF SHADOWS</p>



    <div class="blur author"></div>
    <p class="p2">JUNICHI</br>RO</br>TANI</br>ZAKI</p>

</div>
```

In this case, how do I apply the effect to multiple divs? I tried this but I don't think that's how it's supposed to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
let clickCount = 0;

$('.p1').click(function(e) {
    if (clickCount % 2 == 0) {
        $('.title,').toggleClass('fullscreen');
    } else {
        $(".title, .p1").fadeOut(1000);
    }
    clickCount++;
});

$('.p2').click(function(e) {
    if (clickCount % 2 == 0) {
        $('.author').toggleClass('fullscreen');
    } else {
        $(".author, .p2").fadeOut(1000);
    }
    clickCount++;
});
```

Thank you for helping !!!!

Comment: Please find my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple containers with the content you can set attribute of each parent elements on click and set the visibility of the child nodes accordingly.

Please find a sample below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let clickCount = 0;
  $('.p1').click(function(e) {
    const attr = e.target.getAttribute('clickedonce');
    const closestNode = e.target.closest('.container');
    if (attr) {
      e.target.setAttribute('clickedonce', false);
      $(closestNode).find('.title').fadeOut(1000);
      $(closestNode).find('.p1').fadeOut(1000);
    } else {
      $(closestNode).find('.title').toggleClass('fullscreen');
      // Set a custom attribute to the parent node
      e.target.setAttribute('clickedonce', true);
    }    
  });
});
```

```css
.fullscreen {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="blur title">
    Container 1
  </div>
  <p class="p1">
    IN Container 1
    </br>
    PRAISE
    </br>
    OF SHADOWS
  </p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="blur title">
    Container 2
  </div>
  <p class="p1">
    IN Container 2
    </br>
    PRAISE
    </br>
    OF SHADOWS
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! I'm wondering if I had more than one div, how would I apply this effect to all the divs?

Comment: @ZoeCui Yes this is possible. Please find the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

i adjust your code, to better understand the example i add "title" color with fullscreen class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var toggle = false;
  $('.p1').click(function(e) {
      if(toggle === false){
        $('.title').toggleClass('fullscreen');
        toggle = true;
      }else{
        $(".title, .p1").fadeOut(1000);
      }
   });
});
```

```css
.fullscreen{
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="blur title">title</div>
    <p class='p1'>IN <br> PRAISE <br> OF SHADOWS</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! I'm wondering if I had more than one div, how would I apply this effect to all the divs? I tried to repeat this on another div but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: i need to see whole structure. for now you can reply code.

Comment: Is there a way to show you the whole structure of my code? I'm new to this platform so I'm not sure. My code is kinda long.

Answer (score 0):

the best option here is to use a boolean variable to keep the state of your div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isExpanded = false;

    $('.p1').click(function(e) {
       isExpanded = !isExpanded;
       if (isExpanded) {
           $(".title, .p1").fadeOut(1000);
       } else {
          $('.title').toggleClass('fullscreen');
       }
    });
});
```